# Check image not working properly in uitableviewcell over button, tag and cell reuse issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton

Check Images removing after scrolling.
I have to reuse cell and also dont want to use **didselectrow** method because i am having several buttons in one cell and this is the sample i created for stackoverflow.

[image: screenshot of tableview]
I searched a lot in google and found helpless.

Here Is my Sample Code

```
//
//  TVViewController.h
//  tableviewcheck



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TVViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

    UITableView *sampleTableView;
    UIImageView * imageView1;
    UIButton* aButton1;
    UIImageView *imageViewchk1;
    int tag;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *sampleTableView;

@end


//  TVViewController.m
//  tableviewcheck

#import "TVViewController.h"

@interface TVViewController ()

@end

@implementation TVViewController
@synthesize sampleTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    // Usually the number of items in your array (the one that holds your list)
    //  NSLog(@"selected %i and deliveryArray %i",[queueArray count],[deliveryArray count]);
                return 50;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Where we configure the cell in each row

    // NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i", indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    }
        imageViewchk1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(56,0 , 24,24)];
        imageViewchk1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
        imageViewchk1.tag=indexPath.row+10000;
          imageViewchk1.hidden=YES;

        imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80)];
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newframe.png"];

        aButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton1 setTag:indexPath.row];
        [aButton1 setImage:imageView1.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80);
        [aButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [aButton1 addSubview:imageViewchk1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton1];

    return cell;

       }


-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {
    tag = sender.tag;
    NSLog(@"buttonClicked %i",tag);

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[sampleTableView viewWithTag:tag+10000];


        if(imageView.hidden)
        {
            imageView.hidden=NO;
        }
        else {
            imageView.hidden=YES;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem with you implementation is, that you only set the imageView.hidden property in the buttonClicked method.

When a cell is not shown on the screen for a moment and then shown again, cellForRow is called again.

The problem here is, that you do not store in which cell the imageView.hidden has been set to NO. That is why every time a cell is shown again, the cellForRow: sets its imageView.hidden to YES.

So solution will be to store the numbers of the cell, where imageView.hidden= NO and check in cellForRow if the cell at that indexpath is one where imageView.hidden= NO.

Answer (score 0):

Answering My Own Question For the People searching same Functionality, Here How i did the changes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int count=0;count<50;count++)
        [tempArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    // Usually the number of items in your array (the one that holds your list)
    //  NSLog(@"selected %i and deliveryArray %i",[queueArray count],[deliveryArray count]);
                return 50;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];



    }

    imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80)];
    imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newframe.png"];

    imageViewchk1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(56,0 , 24,24)];
    imageViewchk1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    imageViewchk1.tag=indexPath.row+10000;
    imageViewchk1.hidden=YES;


    aButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [aButton1 setTag:indexPath.row];
    [aButton1 setImage:imageView1.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80);
    [aButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButton1 addSubview:imageViewchk1];


   BOOL selected=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if(selected)
    {
      //  imageViewchk1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];

        imageViewchk1.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
      imageViewchk1.hidden=YES;
    }

      [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton1];

    return cell;

       }



-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {
    tag = sender.tag;
    NSLog(@"buttonClicked %i",tag);


     NSIndexPath *index=[sampleTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
     BOOL selected=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:index.row] boolValue];
    if(selected)
    {
     [tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
    else
    [tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    [sampleTableView reloadData];


    }
```